# Google docs api insert column break

Tags: google-docs-api

How to insert column break using google docs api v1? There are methods like `insertPageBreak` and `insertSectionBreak` but nothing for column break.

Comment: I cannot understand about `column break` in your question. I apologize for this. In order to correctly understand about your goal, can you provide the sample input and output you expect as images?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Unfortunately, what you want cannot be achieved.

When updating a Google Doc, the only options are indeed only the ones to insert a page break or a section break.

However, the `ParagraphElement` contains a `ColumnBreak` element. So when creating a document using the below request, you can specify directly where you would like to place the `ColumnBreak`

**Request**

```
POST https://docs.googleapis.com/v1/documents
```

**Body**

```
"paragraph": {
    "elements": [{
        "startIndex": start_index,
        "endIndex": end_index,
        "columnBreak": {
            "textStyle": {}
        }
    }]
}
```

What you can do in this situation is to file a request on Google's Issue Tracker [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=555502&template=1211190) and provide all the necessary details.

#### Reference

- [Google Docs API batch.Update](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/documents/request#request);
- [Google Docs API ParagraphElement](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/documents#paragraphelement);
- [Google Docs API documents.create](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/documents/create).

Comment: Related feature-request -> [DocumentApp - Ability to append column break](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/175510662)